# Exception is not thrown in coressponding try block

Tags: java

I am trying execute below code. But I am getting compile time errors. I have written below code to display the contents of the file "myfile.txt". 
But Actually there is no file "myfile.txt". Then an exception "FileNotFound" should be thrown at run time. But the below programme is not compiled.

### Why am i getting compile time errors?

code:

```
import java.io.*;
class rethrow {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        rethrow rt = new rethrow();
        try {
            rt.m1();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException FNFE) {
            FNFE.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void m1() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
            System.out.println("file contents");
            int ch;
            while ((ch = fin.read()) != -1)
                System.out.println((char) ch);
            fin.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException FNFE) {
            FNFE.printStackTrace();
            throw FNFE;
        } catch (IOException IOE) {
            IOE.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

---------------------------`---------------------------
OUT PUT:

```
rethrow.java:11: exception java.io.FileNotFoundException is never thrown in bod
y of corresponding try statement
catch(FileNotFoundException FNFE)
^

rethrow.java:30: unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be ca
ught or declared to be thrown
throw FNFE;
^
2 errors
```

Comment: your method m1 should look like that `void m1() throws FileNotFoundException`. But rethrowing it at `throw FNFE` is quite unneccessary.

Answer (score 2):

you have to add the throws clause in method `m1`:

```
  void m1() throws FileNotFoundException {
```

otherwise you have a **Unreachable catch block for FileNotFoundException** in your `main` method and **Unhandled exception type FileNotFoundException** in your method `m1`.

catching the exception in m1 is not necessary with that change.

Comment: Thanks . I have understood.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your method as following

```
void m1() throws FileNotFoundException
{
 try
 {
  FileInputStream fin=new FileInputStream("myfile.txt");
  System.out.println("file contents");
  int ch;
  while((ch=fin.read())!= -1)
  {
   System.out.println((char)ch);

  }
  fin.close();
 }
 catch(FileNotFoundException FNFE)
 {
   FNFE.printStackTrace();
   throw FNFE;
 }
 catch(IOException IOE)
 {
  IOE.printStackTrace();
 }
}
```

> You should declare what type of exceptions your method throws to the calling method.